# When do two matrices have the same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Recently I started learning about matrices and know for example that the pivot columns of a matrix form a basis for the column space of this matrix.

I just can't seem to find out when two matrices have the same column space. Wouldn't it be enough to show that both the matrices have the same reduced echolon form (like with the null space) and therefore the same basis for the column space and thus the same column space?

Can someone help me on this?

Edit:
Maybe another question: how can you tell that two matrices don't have the same column space? Can I for example use the fact that if two matrices don't have the same dimension for the column space, that the column spaces cannot be equal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you row-reduce a matrix, the **dimension** of the column space stays fixed, so if $A,B$ have the same reduced echolon form then the **dimensions** of the column spaces are equal, but the column spaces might not be equal: 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}\hspace{10pt}B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}$$
The have the same reduced echolon form, but different column-spaces.
In general, the only way to make sure that two matrices have the same column space is to *column*-reduce them (unless both are of full rank).

Comment: thank you for the help, but i'm aware of the fact that if two matrices have the same echolon form they have the same dimension. Is there no other way to know if two matrices have the same column space? I edited the question

Comment: And what do you mean with "unless both are of full rank" ?

Comment: Any two matrices of full rank (i.e. square matrices with rank equal to the number of columns) have the same row space and the same column space (which will be $F^n$ where $n$ is the number of rows/columns)

Comment: So it actually means that if there are pivots in every column for both matrices, than they have the same column space? In other words: if the dimensions of the column space of two matrices are the same and the dimension is equal to the number of columns than they have the same column space? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes - beacuse $n$ linearly independent vectors in $F^n$ span $F^n$

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much! :)

Comment: What do you mean to "column reduce them"?

Comment: Use column operations to get to the reduced form - in the columns

Comment: Does the same definition of column space holds over commutative ring?

Answer (score 11):

Let $A, B \in \mathrm{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{K})$ be two matrices with $m$ rows, $n$ columns and entries in the field $\mathbb{K}$.

The following statements are equivalent:

1. there exists an invertible matrix $P \in \mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb{K})$ such that $B = P A$;
2. there exists a finite sequence of elementary Gauss operations on the rows that transforms $A$ into $B$;
3. the subspaces of $\mathbb{K}^m$ generated by the rows of $A$ and $B$, respectively, are equal.

The following statements are equivalent:

1. there exists an invertible matrix $P \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{K})$ such that $B = A P$;
2. there exists a finite sequence of elementary Gauss operations on the columns that transforms $A$ into $B$;
3. the subspaces of $\mathbb{K}^n$ generated by the columns of $A$ and $B$, respectively, are equal.

Comment: thank you for the help, but I don't get your answer, especially the second statements. Do you mean that if I column reduce a matrix and get the other matrix as a result that they will have the same column space? If yes, would this also hold for augmented matrices (with different solutions?). And how does reducing with columns work, would you be so kind to show me an example? :). Oh, and I edited the question

Comment: This is great(!) but I think you need to switch $\mathbb K^m$ and $\mathbb K^m$ in statements 3.  Do you have a source for this that I can see the proof and cite?

Comment: Thanks for this.  
So for your second set of equivalent statements, is the following interpretation correct:  
So for two matrices with the same column space, we can apply elementary column operations two one of the matrices to equate the two matrices. Then as the matrix given by the product of elementary column operations is invertible, we can say that there exists an invertible matrix such that taking the product equates the matrices?